# Firebase script not signed - Powershell

Tags: node.js, firebase, powershell, google-cloud-functions

I'm setting up a new project with Firebase and after running the command `firebase init functions`, I get the error below.

```
firebase : File C:\Users\fudge\AppData\Roaming\npm\firebase.ps1 cannot be loaded. The file C:\Users\fudge\AppData\Roaming\npm\firebase.ps1 is not digitally signed. 
You cannot run this script on the current system. For more information about running scripts and setting execution policy, see about_Execution_Policies at 
https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.
At line:1 char:1
+ firebase init functions
+ ~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [], PSSecurityException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess
```

I know that I can run

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted
```

to allow it to run, but that seems dangerous as I imagine I would also allow malicious scripts to run if my PC ever got any. Is there any reason why the Firebase package isn't digitally signed and is there anyway to use `firebase` without changing the Execution Policy?

Before the init command I only used these three commands, using Node v12.14.0:

```
npm init
npm install firebase-functions@latest firebase-admin@latest --save
npm install -g firebase-tools
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll run into many scripts that are not signed. Only the author can answer:

> ***Is there any reason why the Firebase package isn't digitally signed***

... this would be true for any unsigned script you'd encounter. All that being said, nothing prevents you from signing any script, from anyone else, if it is not. That, however, is your choice.

Depending on what version of PowerShell you are running, at the default install, the OS level config, the ExecutionPolicy is set to restricted by design.

This does not prevent you from running scripts at all, as you can load the script the ISE and hit F8 and it will run. The firebase script will likely run in a command prompt.

You could copy and paste the whole script into the consolehost, and it will run as well, once you hit enter.

This, of course, is not the automated way of running scripts.

Current ExecutionPolicy settings are set to RemoteSigned by default, so local scripts can run, all other scripts must be signed in order to run them.

There are many ways to allow PowerShell scripts to run, without changing the host OS ExecutionPolicy setting. In most enterprises, this setting is made and enforced via GPO. If that is your case, now or future, then you would not be able to change it anyway.

The PowerShell ExecutionPolicy has a scope, and you can use any of those to run scripts in the user context, or even the process context, with a given ExecutionPolicy that is only in effect during the run.

As per the help files:

> [About Execution Policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_execution_policies?view=powershell-6)
>
> Execution policy scope You can set an execution policy that is
> effective only in a particular scope.
>
> The valid values for Scope are:
>
> MachinePolicy, UserPolicy, Process, CurrentUser, and LocalMachine.
>
> LocalMachine is the default when setting an execution policy.
>
> The Scope values are listed in the precedence order. The policy that takes
> precedence is effective in the current session, even if a more
> restrictive policy was set at a lower level of precedence.
>
> For more information, see Set-ExecutionPolicy.
>
> MachinePolicy Set by a Group Policy for all users of the computer.
>
> UserPolicy Set by a Group Policy for the current user of the computer.
>
> ***Process***
>
> ***The Process scope only affects the current PowerShell session.***
>
> The execution policy is saved in the environment variable
> $env:PSExecutionPolicyPreference, rather than the registry. When the
> PowerShell session is closed, the variable and value are deleted.
>
> ***CurrentUser***
>
> ***The execution policy affects only the current user.*** It's
> stored in the HKEY_CURRENT_USER registry subkey.
>
> LocalMachine The execution policy affects all users on the current
> computer. It's stored in the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE registry subkey.

There are many ways to bypass restrictive execution policies as noted here:

> [15 Ways to Bypass the PowerShell Execution Policy](https://blog.netspi.com/15-ways-to-bypass-the-powershell-execution-policy)

Your concern about setting the default OS ExecutionPolicy to Unrestricted is prudent. Don't, as per the above there is little reason to set it that way. Set your ExecutionPolicy per session or user.

Comment: The relevant command you'll want if you want to set your user execution policy to unrestricted (the bottom of that "15 ways" list): 

Set-Executionpolicy -Scope CurrentUser -ExecutionPolicy UnRestricted

Comment: It's not a valid point to ignore security simply because it can be easily bypassed.

Answer (score 7):

I was getting the same error in the VSCode terminal, so I ran the command into the command prompt and it worked for me.

Comment: What Script? could specify the script that worked for you.

Comment: @Moha_a_Osman the command that I was trying to run worked in CMD prompt. Not the "script" in the strictest sense. Ik this is a year old but just leaving this here for future readers

Answer (score 2):

I get you covered, I have a detailed topic on this Firebase issue just check it out here: https://dev.to/vvhybe/firebase-powershell-execution-policy-20ko

it's a step-by-step guide to how you can run `firebase.psl` in your machine without exposing it to malicious scripts and making it vulnerable by passing the Pwoershel `Execution Policy` using this malicious portal command:

```bash
Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted
```

Answer (score 0):

To be on a safer side it is better to give access only to session and after achieving your aim, and the session is closed, the Security Execution Policy will revert to its default settings.

Kindly use the following:

pwsh.exe -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted

Then you will be able to use the firebase login and flutterfire configure commands.